# Help with Silverlight Sockets and Message delivery

Tags: silverlight, sockets

There are 4 months since I stopped developing my Silverlight Multiplayer Chess game.

[alt text http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/8355/chess.gif](http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/8355/chess.gif)

The problem was a bug wich I couldn't reproduce. I am very sad because this was a test and many Silverlight multiplayer games will come if this will be a success. There are no examples on the internet about how to do stuff like that, not to mention that only few people use Sockets in their programming life.

Since I got some free time this week I managed to discover the problem and I am now able to reproduce the bug.

It seems that if I send 10 messages from client, one after another, with no delay between them, just like in the below example

```
// when I press Enter, the client will 10 messages with no delay between them
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter && textBox.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            MessageBuilder mb = new MessageBuilder();
            mb.Writer.Write((byte)GameCommands.NewChatMessageInTable);
            mb.Writer.Write(string.Format("{0}{2}: {1}", ClientVars.PlayerNickname, textBox.Text, i));
            SendChatMessageEvent(mb.GetMessage());

            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        textBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}

    // the method used by client to send a message to server
    public void SendData(Message message)
    {
        if (socket.Connected)
        {
            SocketAsyncEventArgs myMsg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            myMsg.RemoteEndPoint = socket.RemoteEndPoint;
            byte[] buffer = message.Buffer;
            myMsg.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            socket.SendAsync(myMsg);
        }
        else
        {
            string err = "Server does not respond. You are disconnected.";
            socket.Close();
            uiContext.Post(this.uiClient.ProcessOnErrorData, err);
        }
    }

    // the method used by server to receive data from client
    private void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult async)
    {
        ClientSocketPacket client = async.AsyncState as ClientSocketPacket;
        int count = 0;
        try
        {
            if (client.Socket.Connected)
                count = client.Socket.EndReceive(async);
            // THE PROBLEM IS HERE
            // IF SERVER WAS RECEIVE ALL MESSAGES SEPARATELY, ONE BY ONE, THE COUNT
            // WAS ALWAYS 15, BUT BECAUSE THE SERVER RECEIVE 3 MESSAGES IN 1, THE COUNT
            // IS SOMETIME 45
        }
        catch 
        {
            HandleException(client);
        }

        client.MessageStream.Write(client.Buffer, 0, count);

        Message message;

        while (client.MessageStream.Read(out message))
        {
            message.Tag = client;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(this.processingThreadEvent.ServerGotData), message);
            totalReceivedBytes += message.Buffer.Length;
        }

        try
        {
            if (client.Socket.Connected)
                client.Socket.BeginReceive(client.Buffer, 0, client.Buffer.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived), client);
        }
        catch 
        {
            HandleException(client);
        }
    }
```

there are sent only 3 big messages, and every big message contain 3 or 4 small messages. This is not the behavior I want.

If I put a 100 milliseconds delay between message delivery, everything is work fine, but in a real world scenario users can send messages to server even at 1 millisecond between them.

1. Are there any settings to be done in order to make the client send only one message at a time, or
2. Even if I receive 3 messages in 1, are they full messages all the time (I dont't want to receive 2.5 messages in one big message) ? because if they are, I can read them and treat this new situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the main feature of TCP - it's not a message-based protocol. It sends all data via single "pipe". When you put 5 cups of water into the pipe, you get a bucket of water on another end, and not five cups. If you are quick enough to take the water out of the bucket, you can get either 5 cups or 10 half-cups or one bucket. The same with TCP. If you need messages, you must put some markers at the beginning and the end of each message, and parse the stream on the receiving end.